# Maintaince of CoreData Application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, macos, core-data

If you change an anything (entity, relationship, type of attribute etc) in a CoreData model after it has shipped, what is the general process that you have to go through to get the user's store updated for your new model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, best practice is to include a version number of the model in your schema.

When the schema changes, you go through "Converters" to update from one version to the next.

By keeping the legacy containers and scheme, you can upgrade any version to the latest.

The conversion process is something you would write yourself, but you should only have to do it once per schema version.

Comment: Thanks. A friend just pointed me to the following document which seems to explain what you mentioned.

http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html